# Equality for Matricies/Tensors of Different dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose you have two matrices A of shape [n,k] and B of shape [m,k]. Your desired output is C of shape [n,m], where each entry [i,j] corresponds to the equality of row A[i] and row B[j]. Implementing this straing forward would look something like this:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        C[i, j] = th.eq(A[i, :], B[j, :]).all().float()
```

Example:

```
A = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

and

```
B = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

the desired output would be:

```
C = [[1., 0., 0., 1.],
     [0., 1., 0., 0.],
     [1., 0., 0., 1.]]
```

The straight forward implementation is quite slow, do you have any ideas how to improve this on cuda hardware with pytorch? Probably without for-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```py
c = (A[:, None, :] == B[None, ...]).all(dim=2).float()
```